# Regex: Exclude or include a match based on word match/not match

Tags: ruby, regex, string-matching, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I would like to match a sentence if few words are present and discard the match if certain other words are present.

For example:

I would like to regex match to happen if the string has "consumer" and "services" and the match not to happen if the string has word "delayed".

Match to happen:

```
"Consumer are offered services based on the plans selected"
```

Match not to happen:

```
"In case ,the consumer services are delayed then penalty shall be beared."
```

Regex written for match:

```
(\b(?:consumer)\b.*?services)
```

Comment: Try `/^(?!.*\bdelayed\b)(?=.*\bconsumer\b)(?=.*\bservices\b)/`

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a regular expression for this? I think the code will be much easier to understand without one:

```
input = 'Consumer are offered services based on the plans selected'

input_lower = input.downcase

input_lower.include?('consumer') &&
  input_lower.include?('services') &&
  !input_lower.include?('delayed')
```

This isn't *exactly* checking what you asked since it's not looking for *word boundaries* (e.g. `'Consumers'` will also match), but that's probably desirable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the negative lookahead:

```
▶ input = ["Consumer are offered services based on the plans selected",
▷   "In case ,the consumer services are delayed then penalty shall be beared."]  

▶ input.map { |line| line =~ /(?!.*delayed)(consumer|services)/ }
#⇒ [21, nil]
```

Comment: Note: *I would like to regex match to happen if the string has "consumer" **and** "services"*. BTW, the trailing `.*` is redundant.